Change programatically Wordpress ContactForm7 DropDown Menu option

List item

I would like to make a very useful WordPress ContactForm7 section within my website. To make it really useful, I would need to alter some drop-down menu's value on the fly with JavaScript.
I didn't find any suitable solution so far in the last days, but tried the following things;
Its quite easy to get access over the selector using JS:
var wpcf7Form = document.querySelector('.wpcf7-form')
var myItem    = wpcf7Form.querySelector('select[name="DropDown_Menu-1"]')

I can even list here the default values of the drop-down menu what I initially set-up in the CF7 edit block:
var SecondValue = myItem[1].value 
var FourthValue = myItem[3].value

But I have difficulties setting new values for the individual drop-down menu items, even if checking back their newly given values within the same snippet seems to be OK! But in reality on the website nothing changed!
myItem[1].value = "new Value"
var NewValue    = myItem[1].value    // and the value is now >new Value< but on the website the menus 2nd element remains the old value

Any idea how to change the values programmatically?

You probably want to change the text content of the option element as well (that's what gets displayed to the user), and not just its submission value.

sorry, I need here more explanation!

You may want to change the <option> displayed text which is different from the option attribute value which is hidden (not displayed):
<option value="String 1 (hidden)">String 1 (displayed)</option>

So you also need to change this displayed option text value, using text property, like:
var myItem      = wpcf7Form.querySelector('select[name="menu-1"]');
var secondValue = myItem[1].value;
var secondText  = myItem[1].text;

myItem[1].value = "new Value"; // Change hidden value
myItem[1].text  = "new Value"; // Change the displayed text (value)

var NewValue    = myItem[1].value // (hidden real value) 
var NewText     = myItem[1].text // (displayed text value)

Now it should work as expected.

do you have any idea as well how to add a new line to the selector's list? the myItem.push ("New Line") is not working, just like the forced new line like myItem['max Line number + 1].value/text = "New Line" either.
